# Electronic circuit - throughput

Tags: vhdl

On a picture below, we have a scheme of an electronic (digital) circuit. What's the throughput of this circuit (Mbit/s)? What is the simplest way to increase throughput? Calculate this throughput.
8 means 8bit.

[image]

Finding throughput of this is pretty simple, 8/(11ns+8ns+4ns)=...

But what about the increasing throughput? How do I do that? And how would it be different, if the delays were in opposite order (i.e. 4->8->11)?

Edit:

[image]

What about parallel one?

Comment: I think you have calculated the latency, not the throughput..

Comment: @EugeneSh. 8bit/(23ns)~=348Mbit/s
This is incorrect?

Comment: Depends. Are the stages buffered (pipelined)? If not - that's the method the question is asking.

Comment: Oh, I see. `R` is probably denoting the register. So yeah, that's fine, given the register timing is negligible..

Comment: @EugeneSh. exactly, R means the register. But what about the second part? From what I understand I have to add pipeline register, but where?

Comment: Think! Apparently the throughput will be defined by the slowest part.

Comment: @EugeneSh. So the answer seems to be that I place this register after the block with the biggest latency

Comment: Almost. But the part with 8+4 is slower, right?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Hmm, right. So I place it after 4ns block?

Comment: To get the highest throughput you will need more than one register.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Meh, I am not getting the idea of those registers. So maybe the correct answer is: after 8ns and after 4ns?

Comment: The throughput will be `8/<latency of the slowest stage>`. So if you put registers around `11ns`, the slowest stage will be 4+8, so the TP will be `8/(4+8)`.  If you put register after 8ns, the slowest stage will be `11+8`. If you put both registers, the slowest stage will be `11ns`, which will give you the best TP.

Comment: What is the clock-rate for the registers?

Comment: @EugeneSh. That explains a lot! Could you take a look at original post? I've added a bit more complicated example. Should we add 4 registers here, after blocks 8,8,13,3? Edit: more likely 11,8,13

Comment: @Tut There is no such information given

Comment: Actually, it was meant to be a rhetorical question. You can calculate the maximum theoretical throughput with the given information, but to determine the actual throughput you need to know the clock rate.